# Is it possible to use an automated library to visit already authenticated sites in ruby?

Tags: ruby, authentication, single-sign-on

I would like to be able to use a http request tool (such as capybara or http party or simply plain ol' simple ruby) to authenticate a user against a third party site.

The flow would be: User visits site A, logs on and navigates to siteA.com/foo which contains some simple info about them. User then visits site B. I'd like to pull the info from the foo page to display this.

- Automated tool visits siteA.com/foo (already logged on as user has already been there)
- Gets content of div with id bar
- Displays content to user on siteB.com

My question is - is this possible? Or should I stop wasting my time? I have no control over site A, except that I can control the markup.

Comment: It should not be possible, unless the user copies the `div` contents by himself and pastes them on site B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the owner of site A not provide an API from which you can collect the data that you want?

You can use something like [faraday](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/) to provide authentication to pull data from site A, then save it however you like (as raw markup in an object, if you wish) and show it on site B.

I guess the next question of where your ruby code will be running (as part of site B, or on a server completely separate from either site?), and how you're going to get the data from the ruby code over to site B. Simply authenticating, and reading/parsing in the data on site A is pretty easy on its own.

Comment: No, they don't supply an API unfortunately. Ruby code will be part of siteB. Faraday looks like a good start, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.